# I am trying to add elements to an array which is in another activity and i get an error. what can i do?

Tags: android, arrays

I am building a browser and i have a Favorites page which is a ListActivity and i want to add elements to the Favorites, through an array, because that's how i made it. This is the code for the list activity:

```
package com.example.browser3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Favorite extends ListActivity {

String[] elements={""};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
HomePage object=new HomePage();





public void setElements(int position,String element) {
    elements[position]=element;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorite.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , elements));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.browser3.HomePage");// ce e aici aia porneste la click
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Favorite.this , ourClass);
    String s=elements[position];
    ourIntent.putExtra("name", s);
    startActivity(ourIntent);


            }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and this is the code from the Settings Activity where I have an EditText and a Button to add the elements to the array:

```
 package com.example.browser3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Settings extends Activity {

TextView tvCurrentHomePage2;
EditText etHomepage;
Button bAdd;
Button bMenu;
HomePage obj= new HomePage();
String home;
EditText etAdress;
Button bAdd1;
Button bRemove;
Favorite obje=new Favorite();

private void clickHome(){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.browser3.MENU"));
}

protected void onResume() {
    readFile("home.txt", tvCurrentHomePage2);

    super.onResume();
}
public void readFile2(String fileName, String[] w) {   //cea pentru favorite
    try {
        InputStream in = openFileInput(fileName);
        if (in != null) {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str;
            while ((str = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(str + "\n");
                w=null;

                String b = builder.toString();
                String lines[] = b.split("\\r?\\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    w[i]=lines[i];
                }

            }
            in.close();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeFile(String fileName, EditText x) {

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_APPEND));
        out.write(x.getText().toString() + "\n");
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void clearFile(String fileName) {        //goleste fisierul

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, 0));
        out.write(" ");

        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    tvCurrentHomePage2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentHomePage2);
    etHomepage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHomepage);
    bAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    bMenu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bMenu);

    bMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickHome();                
        }
    });
etAdress=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);

    bAdd1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd1);
    bAdd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            writeFile("favorite.txt",etAdress);
            readFile2("favorite.txt", obje.elements);

        }
    });

    bRemove= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
    bRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearFile("favorite.txt");
            for(int j=0;j<obje.elements.length;j++){
                obje.setElements(j,null);
            }

        }
    });







}   
}
```

In my opinion, it should work, but it crashes. Can someone help me please?

The LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.browser3.Settings.readFile2(Settings.java:82)
at com.example.browser3.Settings$3.onClick(Settings.java:178)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: stacktrace... Paste your error

Comment: Paste the complete stacktrace, NEP is too broad to debug

Comment: i copied the logcat. i'm sure the error isn't in the try/catch. it is when i click the Add1 button in Settings Activity

Comment: You cannot instantiate Activities like this: `Favorite obje=new Favorite()`, `HomePage object=new HomePage()`.

Comment: I thought it was just an object for that class to access the data. so it's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to access slots in a null array ...

```
w=null; // You shouldn't do this... Why are you setting this to null ?
```

then later in a for loop

```
w[i] // Not going to work if w is null
```

This would probably be better :

```
public List<String> readFile2(String fileName) {   //cea pentru favorite
    try {
        InputStream in = openFileInput(fileName);
        if (in != null) {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str;
            while ((str = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(str + "\n");

                String b = builder.toString();
                String lines[] = b.split("\\r?\\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    result.add(lines[i]);
                }

            }
            in.close();
            return result; // returning the result of the execution of the method is probably better than passing an array as argument.
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally, as pointed out by Mike M, *you cannot instantiate Activities like this: Favorite obje=new Favorite()* ... If you need to use objects form other Activities in your Activity, pass them as Intent extras.

Comment: I want the array to be empty when i start adding things to it

Comment: Use ArrayList<String> and then add each url's to it

Comment: 2 things : when you do w = null(setting reference to null, you cannot use that reference anymore), it's different from doing w = new String[10] (initializing the array so it can be used) ... You need to initialize your array, and you need to do it outside the while loop otherwise you initialize it to an empty array for every line of the file(every iteration of the while loop), and not just once.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in function readFile2(...)

```
 w=null;   // You are assigning null

 String b = builder.toString();
 String lines[] = b.split("\\r?\\n");

 for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    w[i]=lines[i]; // Then accessing here
 }
```

This is the bug

EDIT:
since you are copying each element of lines to w, rather do this

```
w = lines;
```

EDIT 2: Sorry reference was lost after reassigning w, dont pass array at all and do like this in readfile2

```
  obje.elements = lines;
```

Comment: i removed it. still crashes

Comment: yeah because the size of w may not be the size of lines, see my edited answer

Comment: i did w=lines; and it doesn't crash anymore, but the Favorites List remains empty.